# how do I find the index of an specific value in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `numpy array` with size `(1000,6)` and I fill part of it each time during my program. I need to find the first location of zero in this array. for this, I used `np.where( array==0)`. but the output is a `tuple` of size 2 and each item of it is a numpy array and I do not how can I find the first index of occurring zero in this array. what should I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere):

```
tuple(np.argwhere(a == 0)[0])
```

---

If you want to use `np.where`, then you can do:

```
next(zip(*np.where(array == 0)))
```

That tuple of arrays you got were the indices for each axis. We can zip them together to get coordinate pairs. Then we call `next` on the zip iterator to get the first element from it, i.e. the coordinates of the first `0` found by `np.where`. You can test that these are the coordinates for the zeros by verifying that the when we use them as indexes for `array` it always outputs zero:

```
[array[x] for x in zip(*np.where(array == 0))]
```

---

Both of these approaches have the disadvantage of operating on the entire array, when they ought to stop after the first match. Stopping after the first match is a feature request that can be tracked here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269

Answer (score 1):

The first element of the tuple that you got should be the index you are looking.